# Check how many object properties are defined

Tags: scala

I'm quite new in Scala world.
Is there a better way to check how many properties are defined in an object, rather than going through all of them with `idDefined()` and incrementing a value?

```
case class Obj (
 a: Option[String],
 b: Option[String],
 c: Option[String],
 d: Option[String]
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Case classes extend `Product` which provides `productIterator`. You could use it like:

```
val obj = Obj(Some("a") ,Some("4"), None, None)

obj.productIterator.count {
   case _: Some[_] => true
   case _ => false
} // returns 2
```

or

```
obj.productIterator.count {
   case x: Option[_] => x.isDefined
   case _ => false
} // returns 2
```